# Bad render alert solution?

Tags: web-development-server

Any party know of a product which will alert if a website renders bad - different than alert if the website is down.

If the http service is operating and the rendered output includes keywords such as "error" then i would like a notification. this is different than if the http service is not available.

for scenarios if consultant makes changes and the website is producing an error or not rendering as expected.

Bad render = Any error or missing closing tags, or accepts user defined keywords or regex.

This service is intended to assist a party in the role of customer who would not be participating in the backend alert notifications an IT admin may receive from their web server etc.

Comment: "not rendering as expected" is way too broad. Are you talking about a specific error code, a la 404? what kind of server are we talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'renders bad'? If you're asking whether the outputted HTML is different from some known-good version, you want something like [Nagios](http://www.google.ca/search?q=nagios), and this question belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

If your website renders as valid XHTML you can run it through the W3C markup validation service periodically to check for errors.

There isn't anything that I know of in a browser that will return a "render status."  Even if it did, this wouldn't save you from non-standards-compliant browsers that render things badly.  You have to eyeball that.

Answer (score 0):

Tembria or Freshwater SiteScope (Acquired by HP) has been suggested.

Any know of opensource options?